# I am new to react and I'm not sure how to implement the stripe Elements in my app.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments, e-commerce, mern

My App.js looks like this

```js
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom' 
import { Elements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js'

function App() {

  const [stripeApiKey, setStripeApiKey] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    store.dispatch(loadUser())

    async function getStripApiKey() {
      const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/stripeapi');

      setStripeApiKey(data.stripeApiKey)
    }

    getStripApiKey();

  }, [])

  return (
            <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes>
                {stripeApiKey && 
                   <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}>
                      <Route path = "/payment" element={<Payment/>} exact/>
                   </Elements>
              </Routes>
           
          }
```

The browser returns an error saying that the elements is not a route component but I don't know how else to render it. I read the stripe/react documentation sample but i still cant get it to work.

I keep getting this error in my console

"index.tsx:19 Uncaught (in promise) Error: [Elements] is not a  component. All component children of < Routes > must be a < Route > or <React.Fragment>"

Comment: Payment should be a component that renders something, In your code, Payment isn't imported. and you are trying to route to it.

Comment: Oh I actually imported it, I forgot to add it to this file

Comment: Payment has a return

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear: within a , all direct children must be routes.

Move the  wrap inside element={...}.

try this code it should work.

happy coding !

```
        <Route path = "/payment" element={ stripeApiKey && 
          <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeApiKey)}> <Payment/> </Elements>} exact/>
```